# How can I create an upload_to folder that is named a field belonging to the model that is simultaneously being created?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, file-upload, dynamic-programming

**Context:** I'm building a car dealership app using Django 3.1.4, and trying to implement a feature where by every time a new ad is created, so is a new folder (via the upload_to method) within /media/ that will only contain that newly created ad's photos.

I've gotten this working somewhat using date formatting (see below) but I need this new folder to be named one of the fields belonging to the model(see the second code snippet).

```
photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
```

For example, every newly created ad would use the title field..

```
class Vehicles(models.Model):
    CONDITION_CHOICES = [("Brand New","Brand New"),("Used", "Used")]
    FUEL_CHOICES = [("Petrol","Petrol"),("Diesel", "Diesel"),("Electric", "Electric"),("Hybrid", "Hybrid")]
    TRANSMISSION_CHOICES = [("Automatic","Automatic"),("Manual", "Manual")]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default = "Ad Title & Folder Name")
    def folder_name(self, title):
        return self.title
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Ideally then, the media folder would look something like

```
/media/
    Opel Astra VXR/
    Mercedes E200/
```

I understand that many others have done something similar but all the examples I found use the 'user' and instead I need to use a model field (belonging to the model that is being created) as the folder name.

**Closing notes:**
The function in the second code snippet was just something I was trialing.

Also, this is still in development, so in prod I fully intent to direct all media to an S3 bucket down the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

> upload_to may also be a callable, such as a function. This will be
> called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This
> callable must accept two arguments and return a Unix-style path (with
> forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system. The two
> arguments are:

- instance (   An instance of the model where the FileField is defined. )
- filename (   The filename that was originally given to the file )

> For example:
>
> ```
> def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
>     # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
>     return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your input iklinac! I went off to do more research and came across the soloution which was a formatting issue haha! You got an upvote but it wont show because I've less than 15 rep, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Found the soloution and wanted to post it for the next person who might need it. It turned out to be a syntax issue on my formatting . This did the trick and now opens a new folder for each ad and their photos. It also updates the original folder with any new photos added to the preexisting ad.

Title and function below:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default = "Ad Title & Folder Name")
    def upload_photo_to(self, filename):
        return f'{self.title}/{filename}'
```

Photo field and how it was applied:

```
photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_photo_to, blank=True)
```